# jsoup second element instead of first()

Tags: java, php, jsoup, simple-html-dom

I have translated the **PHP Simple HTML DOM** query:

```
$article->find('td[id$=tdDescription] div a', 1)->plaintext;
```

to the **jsoup** query:

```
resultRow.select("td[id$=tdDescription] > div > a").first().text());
```

as you can see I am acessing the second (1) result in PHP, currently in jsoup with the .first() I am accessing the first result (0) but I would also like to access the second result (1), how would I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`Elements#get()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#get%28int%29) instead. This allows accessing elements by index.

```
resultRow.select("td[id$=tdDescription] > div > a").get(1).text();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `td[id$=tdDescription] > div > a:eq(2)`selector.